# $_POST empty on utf-8 characters

Tags: php, codeigniter, character-encoding

I'm working on a multilingual site with CodeIgniter. There is a form that posts data to controller, but `$_POST` is empty when I start to use Turkish characters like `öçüÜĞ` etc.

I set the charset to:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Form:

```
<form action="translations/save" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <textarea rows="6" cols="60" id="editor_tr" name="editor_tr">Türkçe</textarea>
</form>
```

`$_POST` and `$this->input->post('editor_tr')` returns empty, but I can see the raw post with `file_get_contents("php://input")`.

This one works OK in a normal PHP test, but doesn't work with CodeIgniter. Perhaps my .htaccess file  is causing the issue, but dunno.

Any help is much appreciated.

**UPDATE**:
Here is the output for var_dump as requested.

`var_dump($_POST)` - Without Turkish chars

```
array(3) { ["id"]=> string(12) "news8titleID" ["editor_tr"]=> string(13) "turkish value" ["editor_en"]=> string(13) "english value" }
```

`var_dump($_POST)` - With Turkish chars (The input was: `Türkçe karakter`, but it doesn't show up in the $_POST)

```
array(3) { ["id"]=> string(12) "news8titleID" ["editor_tr"]=> string(0) "" ["editor_en"]=> string(13) "english value" }
```

**UPDATE 2:**
When debugging, I have found out that `system.core.Input` class cleans the input data on `_clean_input_data` function.

```
// Clean UTF-8 if supported
if (UTF8_ENABLED === TRUE)
{
    $str = $this->uni->clean_string($str);
}
```

So, before the `$_POST` has reached to my controller, the `editor_tr` value is already cleaned by `system.core.Utf8` class in this function:

```
function clean_string($str)
{
    if ($this->_is_ascii($str) === FALSE)
    {
        $str = @iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $str);
    }

    return $str;
}
```

Comment: have you tried mbstring? and the associated fix for [codeigniter](http://www.haughin.com/2010/02/23/building-utf8-compatible-codeigniter-applications/)

Comment: `My .htaccess file perhaps is causing the issue, but dunno.` Consider supplying it then ?

Comment: @Madmartigan Sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: @Dr.J I implemented mbstring to my codeigniter after your comment, but still no luck. It ignores the element in the $_POST when it has utf-8 chars.

Comment: @Khez Here is my .htaccess file:`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`

Comment: @user What is your output with `var_dump($_POST)` when you submit the string `abc`, and then when you submit the string `Türkçe`? If you add it to the question it will help. I'm kind of interested in this, but I also suspect it may be a simple error on your part, and that this has nothing to do with Codeigniter. I'm also 99.9% certain that .htaccess has nothing to do with it. In the future make sure to add any relevant info *to your question's content* and not in a comment.

Comment: @Madmartigan. Thanks for the feedback and looking into this. I have edited my post and included the `var_dump` output for both.

Comment: @user Please add which version of Codeigniter you are using as well. (1.7.2, 2.0.1, 2.0.2 etc) If you aren't sure just print the constant `CI_VERSION`. And please confirm: You have `application/config/config.php` charset as UTF-8, correct?

Comment: @Madmartigan I'm using CI 2.0, yes, that's correct. I use UTF-8 in my config file: `$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';`

Comment: OK, try one more test please: Try some of these characters `♥ ™ ⅓ “ ”` and we'll see if it's a UTF-8 issue or problem with accented Turkish characters only. It's a long shot but I'm almost out of ideas.

Comment: It didn't like these characters either. I edited my post above for more info.

Comment: Where do the characters in the URL come from? Are you entering them directly into the browser? Does CI have a global "character set" setting and what is it set to?

Comment: @Pekka I have a form and 2 textareas inside. These characters are coming when the user submits the form. The global charset should be utf-8.

Comment: And the form is in a UTF-8 encoded page? The browser shows "UTF-8" in the encoding menu? You have tried removing the preset default and typing in `Türkçe` by hand?

Comment: @user Just want to confirm that I am getting the same issue in CI 2.0.2 as well as 2.0.1 even after manually "disabling" the UTF8 system library. If I submit HelloöçüÜĞ, only Hello is sent.

Comment: @Pekka Yes, the browser shows UTF-8 and I type the chars by ahnd, but still no luck. @Madmartigan Not sure if this is CI bug, I have no problem with displaying the UTF-8, but with the input.

Comment: @user: I think it is indeed a CI bug, I just tried this with fresh default installs of 1.7.2 and 2.0 and had different results. I also `var_dump($_POST)` in the Input class constructor (v2.0.2) and was able to see all the correct characters. This has now consumed my attention and I want to find out what the cause of this is because it is affecting my work as well.

Comment: @Madmartigan Thanks for this valuable information and time you spent on this. Since I'm still in the development phase, I will upgrade to 2.0.2 and test what happens.

Comment: Very strange news: I re-checked versions 1.7.2 to 2.0.2 (5 total versions, default installations) and now I **cannot** reproduce the problem, even though I could before just moments ago! Even stranger: I tried *again* these same characters in your example in my CMS running 2.0.2, and now suddenly they work! I did NOT change anything. Very confused and curious about this issue, maybe it is not CI related?

Comment: One more thing: Make sure you aren't running any validation or prepping rules on the field. Things like `url_title()` will strip those characters.

Comment: @Madmartigan I'm not running any validation rules. I will try to test on a fresh install and give feedback here.

Comment: It seems to be specific to CI running in PHP 5.3.x on MAMP. It does not occur in MAMP PHP 5.2.17, nor is it a problem on my CentOS LAMP server running PHP 5.3.8. I'd love to know what difference is causing the problem in MAMP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the comments are piling up and will probably get overlooked, I am going to post some more suggestions.

Readers please keep in mind this is dealing with $_POST data values and not display of data on a web page.

This user seems to have a similar problem:

[Codeigniter seems to break $_POST of '£' character (Pound)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795682/codeigniter-seems-to-break-post-of-character-pound)

There is a report here on Bitbucket of similar:

<strike>https://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter-reactor/issue/214/problem-when-inserting-special-characters</strike>:
<sub>Removed link: EllisLabs has closed this repo to the public</sub>

Maybe adding this to your index.php will help (probably not):

`ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');`

Double check and make sure you aren't running any validation or prepping rules on the field. Things like `url_title()` will strip those characters.

Comment: The first link you gave solved the problem. Phew. Didn't think that MAMP & PHP would cause this, but you never know. Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's great news, thanks for being so responsive and providing the relevant details promptly. Good luck with your project :)

Comment: Thanks Madmartigan, hope this helps others who run into same issue.

Comment: I spent about 2 hours on this problem, would never guess that MAMP will cause such a funny problem. Thank you :)

Answer (score 6):

Make sure the form tag has accept-charset:

```
<form method="post" action="" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

Then in the controller use utf8_decode() when fetching the posted values:

```
$value = utf8_decode($this->input->post('field_name'));
```

Comment: This should be the accepted solution, or at least upvoted more. The solution at bitbucket provided by Ellislab (in @WesleyMurch answer) is not longer available, since Ellislab closed the repo.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a previous PHP version in your MAMP instalation you can use:

> `$_REQUEST`

To get the data instead of `$_POST`

`$_REQUEST`  is an associative array that by default contains the contents of `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`.

[More info: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)

And that returns all the data that for some reason `$_POST`is breaking !

Answer (score -1):

This isnt an answer, but you might want to take a look and see how everything is coming in.

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $val)
{
     $post_data[$key] => $val;
}
print_r($post_data);
```

then try with CI's post

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $val)
{
     $post_data[$key] => $this->input->post($key);
}

print_r($post_data);
```