# Codeigniter seems to break $_POST of '£' character (Pound)

Tags: codeigniter, post, utf-8, mamp

When I echo $_POST of the '£' character without CI in a simple Form, the result is as expected, a '£'.

When I try the same using the CI framework using the Input class as well as the native $_POST var, echo is a blank.

I've checked to make sure everything is utf-8 in the config but nothing? Any tips?

UPDATE:
This appears to only affect users using the latest version of MAMP and when using PHP 5.3.5. The current workaround is to go to the MAMP control panel and use the earlier version of PHP 5.2.17

For more details see:
https://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter-reactor/issue/214/problem-when-inserting-special-characters

Answer (score 9):

This appears to only affect users using the latest version of MAMP and when using PHP 5.3.5. The current workaround is to go to the MAMP control panel and use the earlier version of PHP 5.2.17

For more details see: https://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter-reactor/issue/214/problem-when-inserting-special-characters

Comment: The page is closed. Anyone knows how to fix this issue ?

Comment: Damn server admins! Took me half a day to find out the server had a PHP update