# How to get accent value from a form name field?

Tags: php, html, forms, utf-8

This a a form with a field

```
<label for="sec1-prenom">Prénom<span class="requis">*</span></label>
<input type="text" name="sec1-prénom" class="required"/>
```

and here is the loop to get the values

```
foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
$myval .= $name .' : '.$value ."\r\n"; }
```

when i do the loop to get the value, the "name" field is : prÀ¢nom (garbage)

what i need to do to get the proper utf8 value ?

---

note, as DAVE said, my for value dont match the name value. question, why it's should. and in fact, i just looking for a proper way to get the value of the label filed, just as written in test with accent and spaces. How i can get that with the $_POST... i think i cannot !

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: or don't use utf-8 characters in field names especially since your lable for= doesn't match your input box name.

Comment: You might want to check for BOM (byte order mark), that could mess up extended ASCII characters at times, it has for me.

Comment: Why it's important to have the SAME name for both. How i can retreive the value of the label in a $_POST ?

Comment: @menardmam actually, `Dave` said that ;) (since your lable for= doesn't match your input box name...)

Comment: @menardmam what "I" said was, you might have a `BOM` issue. I was faced with a similar problem in the past. I since started using `Notepad++` to edit and save my PHP files. Sometimes with and sometimes without the BOM, it depends on how your server is configured.

Comment: @menardmam UTF-8 can be encoded with or without the BOM. Sometimes if you encode `with` the BOM, you will get messed up characters in place of an extended character; i.e. `é, à, è` etc.

Comment: @menardmam If you don't have `Notepad++`, you can download it at the following URL http://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Comment: Let's just "delete" that for="" label... and live happy !

Comment: NO notepad++ for me, i am a MAC person !... holy steve !

Comment: @menardmam I'm sure there are some good text editors out there for the MAC that will let you save in different formats. I kind of have a feeling that you have a `BOM` issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found : [$_POST empty on utf-8 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784207/post-empty-on-utf-8-characters)

in short, the value is already encoded (garbage) so i have to decode it : utf8_decode()

Comment: What exactly is the value submitted as? Show us `bin2hex($name)`.

Comment: You shouldn't have to decode it. You need to find the root of the problem instead of `patching` it.

Comment: By any chance, does the word "Prénom" appear as "PrÃ©nom" or as "PrÀ¢nom" as you originally posted? This is important to know and will definitely tell me that if it does appear as "PrÃ©nom", you have a `BOM` issue.

Comment: @Fred You seem to have an unhealthy obsession with BOMs. If you could at least specify the exact problem instead of just repeating vague references...

Comment: @deceze 8 times out of 10, that's what the problem is.